# Restoring PDBs on a new server

Tags: oracle, backup, rman, oracle-19c, datafile

I am trying to restore a 19c database on a new server using RMAN. What are the prerequisites? Do I have to first create PDBs which are supposed to be restored? Or should I just `restore from controlfile` and then `restore database`?

Can someone help?